# PHP and importing pdf with forms

Tags: php, forms, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm having trouble importing an existing pdf file with forms (text fields, radio buttons...)
with some php libraries like TCPDF, FPDI and PDFlib.
When I import pdf file with forms, do some text print on it, save it, but the output pdf file does not contain forms anymore.

is there a way to do this without loosing forms!
please help
tnx

Answer (score 1):

try [`mpdf`](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/examples)

see the [example](https://docs.google.com/a/offshoretechnolabs.com/viewer?url=http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_forms.pdf)